# Scala function assignment equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, scala, syntax

There's a special syntax in Scala that allows some sort of function "assignment" or return in 1 line. I was wondering if there's something equivalent in C++.

Scala example: `def abs(x: Int) = if (x >= 0) x else -x`

Comment: `int abs(int x) { return x >= 0 ? x : -x; }`?

Comment: It's called a ternary/conditional expression in most languages. Searching that should yield answers.

Comment: Does it make a function or a closure like `auto abs = [](int x){ return x >= 0 ? x : -x;  }`?

Comment: For this example i will just change [ ](int x) to [ ](int x) -> unsigned int since absolute value will always be +ve

Comment: Your question is very unclear. 1) There is no function in your code. 2) There is no assignment in your code. Also, in general, when you ask whether there is something "equivalent", you need to explain what *exactly* you want to be equivalent. First off, if you simply post code in one language and want it to be translated into another language, only someone who is an expert in both languages can answer, whereas if you explain what you want, then every expert in C++ can answer. Secondly, all languages have subtle differences, so it is *impossible* to find something in C++ that is 100% equivalent

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: In order for you code to be equivalent, it needs to be a virtual member function, since the OP's code is a non-final method, and a virtual member function is the closest equivalent to a non-final method. Also, the type needs to be `std::int32_t`, not `int`. And the return type is inferred in the Scala version.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's one of the confusing things about this question. The subject line and the body ask about functions, whereas the code example is a method, which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
int xyz(int x) { return x >= 0 ? x : -x; }
```

For further information please see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_conditional_operator.htm).

Comment: In order for you code to be equivalent, it needs to be a virtual member function, since the OP's code is a non-final method, and a virtual member function is the closest equivalent to a non-final method. Also, the type needs to be `std::int32_t`, not `int`. And the return type is inferred in the Scala version.